# Ajax File Upload in Flask - json response in browser rather than success call

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

So I'm trying to upload a file in flask using ajax, the file seems to upload fine but when returning a response from my view after the form is validated it doesn't go into my ajax function but it seems my browser just displays a white screen with the json shown

Here is a bit of my code - ajax request - using jquery 2.0.3

```
            var form_data = new FormData($('#firmware_file')[0]);
            var url = "{{ url_for('update.update_firmware') }}";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: form_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("YES I DO STUFF HERE IT NEVER FIRES");
                }
            });
```

flask form processing

```
if form2.validate_on_submit():
    uploaded_file = request.files[form2.firmware_file.name]
    file_data = uploaded_file.read()
    return_data = {}
    return_data['uploading'] =  'blerg' #uploaded_file.filename
    file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename))
    open(file_path, 'w').write(file_data)

    APP.decoder.firmware_file = file_path
    APP.decoder.firmware_length = len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == ':', file_data) )

    return jsonify(return_data)
```

Here is the form definition

```
<form id="uploader_manual" class="form-box " method="POST" action="/update/update_firmware" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="firmware_file">
    <label for="firmware_file">Firmware File</label>
    </label>
<div class="controls">
    <input class="firmware_file" id="firmware_file" name="firmware_file" type="file">
    <span class="help-inline"></span>

</div>
</div>                  
<span id="submit-group" class="control-group">
    <span class="form-actions">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit">
    </span>
</span>
</form>
```

This seems to just return a white screen with my "uploading": "filename" json.

Full flask view:

```
@updater.route('/update_firmware', methods=['GET', 'POST'] )
@login_required
@admin_required
def update_firmware():
    current_firmware = APP.decoder.device.version_number
    all_ok = "true"
    form = UpdateFirmwareJSONForm()
    form2 = UpdateFirmwareForm()
    form2.multipart = True
    form.firmware_file_json.choices = []
    data = None
    try:
        response = urllib.urlopen(FIRMWARE_JSON_URL)
    except IOError:
        flash('Cannot connect to server', 'error')
        all_ok = "false"

    if all_ok is "true":
        data = json.loads(response.read())

        counter = 0
        for firmware in data['firmware']:
            form.firmware_file_json.choices.insert(counter,(firmware['file'], firmware['version']))
            counter = counter + 1

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file_name = form.firmware_file_json.data
        zip, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(file_name)
        return_data = {}

        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip) as zf:
            files = [name for name in zf.namelist() if name.endswith('.hex')]
            for filename in files:
                file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', secure_filename(filename))
                file_data = zf.open(filename, 'r').read()
                return_data['uploading'] = filename
                if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    open(file_path, 'w').write(file_data)

                APP.decoder.firmware_file = file_path
                APP.decoder.firmware_length = len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == ':', file_data) )

            zf.close()
        return jsonify(return_data);

    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        uploaded_file = request.files[form2.firmware_file.name]
        file_data = uploaded_file.read()
        return_data = {}
        return_data['uploading'] =  uploaded_file.filename
        file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename))
        open(file_path, 'w').write(file_data)

        APP.decoder.firmware_file = file_path
        APP.decoder.firmware_length = len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == ':', file_data) )


        return jsonify(return_data)

    return render_template('updater/firmware_json.html', current_firmware=current_firmware, form=form, form2=form2, firmwarejson=data, all_ok=all_ok);
```

Comment: Success has stuff, just omitted it - it's never getting executed, it literally renders to this http://imgur.com/a/1lonz

Traceback?  That's possible in and javascript?  Firebug shows the request but then it "redirects" to the blank page shown and cannot grab any firebug info.

Comment: You are returning json so it is showing json.To check the working of success function put `console.log('something')` in it.

Comment: Of course I am returning json - the success function never fires - it acts like it is redirecting.  http://imgur.com/a/1lonz is what I get in the browser.  My template literally goes away and I am taken to a new page on the same page with just my json response.

Answer (score 0):

For most of these cases ,the main problem lies in setting the `contentType` to something . Both of the following two things are set to be false :

> 1. **processData**-Because jQuery will convert the files arrays into strings and the server can't pick it up.
> 2. **contentType**-Set this to false because jQuery defaults to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and doesn't send the files.

See if this is the problem you are facing.

Comment: I've seen this answer on here, tried both as false, same issue with the response

Comment: @weevisss Then try error and complete callback function to see what is your problem and post it here

Comment: They don't fire.  It's like flask's response is acting as a redirect - but the logs don't show any new requests, and I do get a 200 response from my POST.

Comment: You should upload the response code of flask . Where do you and how you implement it.

Comment: I've added the full view to the original comment

note that "form" is also an ajax post that works - it just doesn't involve file uploads 

form2 is the issue

Comment: In your form tag, action='/update/update_firmare' while the route is defined as /update_firmware .why ?  This is 6 o clock in the morning I gotta go to sleep . Will come back and see the problem.

Comment: The decorator provides the prefix

I've solved my issue - thanks a bunch for your help.   I was just not preventing the default action of the button soon enough apparently...

Comment: You should add it as an answer .

Answer (score 0):

I was just not preventing the default action of the button early enough.

Comment: When you are writing an answer here you should add the solution code which worked for you plus explanation .